# How to enable persistence in React Native Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

Why my react native app data disappears when reloading the app? I thought that react-native firestore persistence is enable automatically?

By the way here's the code of enabling persistence in React Native.

```
 useEffect(() => {
const nice = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await firestore().settings({persistence: true});
    console.log(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
nice();
```

}, []);

Comment: What is your Firebase version ?

Comment: It's the latest version of react-native firebase

Comment: @learn2code could you solve the issue?